# How to create join table with extra column with JPA annotations?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need for a project to join 2 SQL tables implemented like this :

[image]

I know that I'm not supposed to implement the table IngredientList as an object cause it's only here for SQL structure.

My code goes like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipe")
public class Recipe {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id_recipe")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="liste_ingredients", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_recette", 
    referencedColumnName = "id_recette"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_ingredient", 
    referencedColumnName = "id_ingredient"))
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;
/* Getter/Setter/Constructor */
}
```

Which is the classic way but with that I lose the Quantity attribute that I want to associate with ingredient. And I don't get how I can work around this without creating an object IngredientList.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind that I got my answer gonna edit it soon with code, for anyone with the same question.